# avoiding side effects implementing OR macro function in lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to implement the macro-function `OR` in Lisp

My attempt:

```
(defmacro or2 (test &rest args)   
   `(if ,test ,test (if  (list ,@args) (or2 ,@args) nil)) )
```

However, if I test with something like this:

```
(or2 (print 1) 2 )

1 
1 
1
```

Whereas with the default `OR`:

```
(or (print 1) 2)

1 
1
```

I understand that this is because of my two `,test` at the beginning of my `if` clause, but I don't see how i could avoid it. How could I avoid applying twice the test effects ?

Answer (score 2):

How would you solve the problem of side-effects if you had to code it by hand?

```
(or2 (print 1) 2)
```

### Intermediate variable

Most probably, you would do this:

```
(let ((value (print 1)))
  (if value value 2))
```

You need to define a local variable which holds the value of the first expression, so that later you can reference the variable instead of re-evaluating the same expression more than once.

But what if you already have a variable named `value` in the lexical context where you expand the code? What if, instead of `2`, you were referencing that other `value`? This problem is named *variable capture*.

### Gensym

In Common Lisp, you introduce a fresh symbol, that is guaranteed to not be already bound to anything, using [`GENSYM`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_gensym.htm).

```
(let ((symbol (gensym)))
  `(let ((,symbol ,test))
     (if ,symbol ,symbol ...)))
```

### Recursive expansion

```
(list ,@args)
```

The above is the same as writing directly `,args`.

But you are confusing macroexpansion and execution times. If you inject `args` directly in the code, it will be evaluated (most likely, this is going to fail as a bad function call). What you want instead is to test if `args` is non-null during macroexpansion.
Besides, you should probably first test if your list of expression contains more than one element, in order to simplify the generated code.
Roughly speaking, you have to take into account the following cases:

- `(or2)` is `nil`
- `(or2 exp)` is the same as `exp`
- `(or2 exp &rest args)` is the same as the following, where `var` is a fresh symbol:

  ```
  `(let ((,var ,exp))
     (if ,var ,var (or2 ,@args)))
  ```

Comment: I have tired for several hours; but I can't figure out  how to put all the elements of your answer together to make it work :(

Comment: @JonathP Sorry to hear that. I'd say that Sylwester's answer gives the kind of code I had in mind. But if you are stuck, you can provide more details in your question with the code you have so far and we can see what is blocking you.

Comment: I have tried several ways (didn't keep a copy of them all). I have added &optional for test and some prints to figure out what was happening. This is my latest lame attempt https://pastebin.com/C0iV0Bv9

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of `macroexpand-1`:

```scm
(macroexpand-1 '(or2 (print 1) 2))
; ==> (if (print 1) (print 1) (if (list 2) (or2 2) nil)) ;
; ==> t
```

With macros you wish the order of evaluation to be expected and you wish expressions to only be evaluated once. Thus the expansion should have been something like this:

```scm
(let ((tmp (print 1)))
  (if tmp
      tmp
      (or2 2)))
```

And `tmp` should be a symbol generated by `gensym`. Also when `args` is `nil` you should expand `or2` to only `test`:

```scm
(defmacro or2 (test &rest args)
  (if (endp args)
      test
      (let ((tmp (gensym "tmp")))   
        `(let ((,tmp ,test))
           (if ,tmp
               ,tmp
               (or2 ,@args))))))
```

you can [make use of macros](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html) to simplify this:

```scm
(defmacro or2 (test &rest args)
  (if (endp args)
      test
      (once-only (test)
        `(if ,test
             ,test
             (or2 ,@args)))))
```